# Regex for finding a pattern in a string

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy, regex-group

I can have string like `switchaubcsp-loafsyvgvhv` which can possibly contain any of the following patterns: `s-loaf`, `p-loaf` etc.

Following is the requirement in detail:

```
1st character - Any of [p,s,a,r,l], 
2nd character -> [-], Followed by Word [loaf].
```

In the above example, when searched for `[p-loaf]`, Found the text `p-loaf` starting at **11** index and ending at index **17** using `java.util.regex`.

What will be the **regular expression** for finding the first character to be `Any of [p,s,a,r,l], 2nd character -> [-], Followed by Word [loaf]`.

Comment: You pretty much have everything you need, including the **character class** of accepted characters, and the constant that follows. What have you tried? (instead of just expecting everything be handed to you)

Comment: @AntonH [psarl][-]loaf

Answer (score 3):

`[psarl]-loaf`
if you want the word to start with it, add `^` to the beginning and if you want the word to end with it, add `$` to the end.

you can try it out here [demo regex](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: I think you are in danger of geting downvotes for a "please write my code"; just in case you get some and wonder why.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.regex.*;
public class RegexExamples {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RegexTag("devicexyzas-loafcdbdd", "[psarl][-]loaf");

    }

    public static void RegexTag(Stri`enter code here`ng Content, String PatternToMatch){
        Pattern pattern;
        try {
            pattern = Pattern.compile(PatternToMatch);
        }
        catch (PatternSyntaxException e)
        {
            System.err.println ("Regex syntax error: " + e.getMessage ());
            System.err.println ("Error description: " + e.getDescription ());
            System.err.println ("Error index: " + e.getIndex ());
            System.err.println ("Erroneous pattern: " + e.getPattern ());
            return;
        }

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(Content);

        System.out.println ("Regex = " + Content);
        System.out.println ("Text = " + PatternToMatch);
        System.out.println ();

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Found the text \"" + matcher.group()
                    + "\" starting at " + matcher.start()
                    + " index and ending at index " + matcher.end());
        }
    }
}
```